# Use one function for 2 different Viewmodels KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have 2 viewmodel one is a header dashbord one just an online piggybank. I want to use function from one js file to another. I take out Profile picture url from a dashboard and put in my div.

```
<a class="icon-box permission desktop" data-local-storage="image" id="changeAvatarHeader" href="@Url.Action("Profile", "User")" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(\'' +  Header().ProfileImage() + '\')' }">
```

II

```
<div class="piggy-user-profile-icon" data-local-storage="image" href="@Url.Action("Profile", "User")" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(\'' +  HeaderModel().ProfileImage() + '\')' }"></div>
```

problem is profileImage is undefined in my second viemodel.

```
function DashboardViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.searchModel = new AuthorizedSearchViewModel();
self.Header = ko.observable(new HeaderModel());
self.UnSeenMessagesCount = ko.observable(0);
self.Messages = ko.observableArray();
self.CanShowRemindProfile = ko.observable(false);
self.Remind = ko.observable(new RemindModel());

self.LoadUserInformation = function () {
    $.post('/User/GetUserInfoForDashboardHeader',
        function (response) {
            InitTawkChat(response);
            self.Header(new HeaderModel(response));
        }, "json").done(function () { console.warn("loaderOff") });
}
```

data function that I use in dashboard is already used on that page so I cant write another in my piggybankjs it will read profile data twice.

```
function HeaderModel (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.Balance = ko.observable();
    self.Name = ko.observable();
    self.ProfileImage = ko.observable('');
    self.CompleteLevel = ko.observable();
}
```

I just want to take ProfileImage out of it

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways of doing this but typically you would move the common data out of the viewmodel into a separated object that you reference everywhere you want to use it. A basic example of this that you can see running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ubpnh7s/):

```
var globalState = {
  user: {
    name: ko.observable(),
    picture: ko.observable()
  }
}


var DashboardViewModel = function() {  

  this.loadUserInformation = function() {
    globalState.user.name("Ozzy Osbourne");
  };

};


var BankViewModel = function() {  
  this.ammount = ko.observable((20).toFixed(2));
};



ko.applyBindings(new DashboardViewModel(), document.getElementById('dashboard'));
ko.applyBindings(new BankViewModel(), document.getElementById('bank'));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dashboard">
  Hello, <span data-bind="text: globalState.user.name"></span>!

  <button data-bind="click:loadUserInformation">
  load user
  </button>
</div>


<div id='bank'>
  <span data-bind="text: globalState.user.name"></span>, you have <span data-bind="text: ammount"></span>!
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate Ill try that

Answer (score 0):

```
self.LoadUserInformation = function () {
    $.post('/User/GetUserInfoForDashboardHeader',
        function (response) {
            InitTawkChat(response);
            self.Header(new HeaderModel(response));
            self.Header().ProfileImage(response.url);
        }, "json").done(function () { console.warn("loaderOff") 
})}
```